# Masonry layout works incorrectly sometimes, but it works after reloading

Tags: javascript, laravel, masonry

https://imagefree.com/en
This is my website, and I have used massonry library. The framework is laravel.

This is my code

```
<script>
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        $masonry = $('.masonry__wrap').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.masonry__item',
            percentPosition: true,
            columnWidth: '.masonry__sizer',
            gutter: 19
        });
     }
</script>
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: WHat do you mean incorrectly?

Comment: Check out the website you will see it. Many images are stacked over each other but it is corrected once we reload the page usually.

Comment: I asking because I don't see any different

Comment: I don't see any difference whatsoever between first and Nth reloads

Answer (score 3):

you can use `imagesloaded` method as per the doc

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var $masonry = $('.masonry__wrap');
    $masonry.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $masonry.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.masonry__item',
            percentPosition: true,
            columnWidth: '.masonry__sizer',
            gutter: 19
        });
    });
});
```

[public demo](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RPKgEN)

Answer (score 0):

Try loading images before initializing masonry. That may resolve your issue.

```
<script>
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

         Promise.all(Array.from(document.images).filter(img => !img.complete).map(img => new Promise(resolve => { img.onload = img.onerror = resolve; }))).then(() => {
            console.log('images finished loading');           

            $masonry = $('.masonry__wrap').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.masonry__item',
                percentPosition: true,
                columnWidth: '.masonry__sizer',
                gutter: 19
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```